# References by multiple authors written both separately and together with authors names written only once?

Tags: biblatex, author-number

The `@xdata` entry type and the `xdata` field are nice as they help us to let redundancy as low as possible, like in the following MCE where long and error prone authors' names:

- de La Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas
- Knuth, Donald Ervin

are written only once, though used in multiple references (the corresponding author fields hold in `@xdata`s `poussin` and `knuth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@xdata{poussin,
  author = {de La Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas},
}
@xdata{knuth,
  author = {Knuth, Donald Ervin},
}

@article{poussin1896a,
  xdata   = {poussin},
  title   = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers},
  journal = {Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles},
  year    = {1896},
  number  = {20},
  pages   = {183-256, 281-352, 363-397}
}
@article{poussin1896b,
  xdata   = {poussin},
  title   = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers},
  journal = {Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles},
  year    = {1896},
  number  = {21},
  pages   = {351-368}
}

@book{knuth1984,
  xdata    = {knuth},
  title    = {The TeXbook},
  date     = {1984-01-14},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
@book{knuth1986,
  xdata    = {knuth},
  title    = {TeX: The Program},
  date     = {1986-01-11},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So far, so good.

Now, imagine the same document contains another reference written by these two authors. Though cascading `@xdata` entries is supported, adding an `@xdata` entry `poussinknuth` referencing `@xdata` entries `poussin` and `knuth` doesn't work as expected: only the last author is taken in account:

```
@xdata{poussinknuth,
  xdata = {poussin,knuth},
}
@article{poussinknuth2019,
  xdata    = {poussinknuth},
  title    = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers, composé avec \TeX},
  journal  = {TUGboat},
  year     = {2019},
  number   = {40},
  pubstate = {inpreparation}
}
```

Okay, this is not surprising, since:

```
@xdata{poussinknuth,
  xdata = {poussin,knuth},
}
```

probably does the something like:

```
@xdata{poussinknuth,
  xdata = {author = {de La Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas},author = {Knuth, Donald Ervin}}
}
```

Hence my question is: is it possible to have, in a `biblatex`'s `.bib`  file, references written by:

- de La Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas
- Knuth, Donald Ervin

both separately and together with the names of these authors written only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the classic approach here (that also works with BibTeX) would be to use `@string`s. Multiple `@string`s can be concatenated with `#`, so you could say

```
author = poussin # { and } # knuth,
```

Your example would then look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@string{poussin = {de La Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas}}
@string{knuth = {Knuth, Donald Ervin}}

@article{poussin1896a,
  author  = poussin,
  title   = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers},
  journal = {Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles},
  year    = {1896},
  number  = {20},
  pages   = {183-256, 281-352, 363-397}
}
@article{poussin1896b,
  author  = poussin,
  title   = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers},
  journal = {Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles},
  year    = {1896},
  number  = {21},
  pages   = {351-368}
}
@book{knuth1984,
  author   = knuth,
  title    = {The TeXbook},
  date     = {1984-01-14},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
@book{knuth1986,
  author   = knuth,
  title    = {TeX: The Program},
  date     = {1986-01-11},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
@article{poussinknuth2019,
  author   = poussin # { and } # knuth,
  title    = {Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers, composé avec \TeX},
  journal  = {TUGboat},
  year     = {2019},
  number   = {40},
  pubstate = {inpreparation}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Donald Ervin Knuth. TeX: The Program. Addison-Wesley, Jan. 11, 1986.//Donald Ervin Knuth. The TeXbook. Addison-Wesley, Jan. 14, 1984.//Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas de La Vallée Poussin. “Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers”. In: Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles 20 (1896), pp. 183–256, 281–352, 63–397.//Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas de La Vallée Poussin. “Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers”. In: Annales de la Société scientifique de Bruxelles 21 (1896), pp. 351–368.//Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas de La Vallée Poussin and Donald Ervin Knuth. “Recherches analytiques de la théorie des nombres premiers, composé avec TeX”. In: TUGboat 40 (2019). In preparation.]

With `xdata` you indeed run into trouble when you want to concatenate `xdata` info for the same field. I guess resolving the

```
@xdata{poussinknuth,
  xdata = {poussin,knuth},
}
```

is highly nontrivial unless Biber starts concatenating multiple occurrences of the same field into one (in the proper fashion!) instead of discarding earlier occurrences.

Comment: I knew about `@string` with `bibtex` but couldn't imagine it would work with `biblatex` since its documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé In general you should be able to assume that all BibTeX idioms also work with `biblatex` (of course there are small differences between Biber/`btparse` and BibTeX, so it is often hard to know what you can assume and what you can't assume). PL decided not to document the general `.bib` format in the `biblatex` manual, and so you can't find documentation of `@string` or `@preamble` there. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/370